# Task switching (alt+tab) doesn't switch the window

Tags: windows-10

Since today's morning, any of my full-screen apps mess up the task switching (alt+tab) function. I can alt+tab but the window (whether it's the one in full-screen or any other), technically, remains in the background and I have to click on it with my mouse or alt+tab to it again to actually select it.
I've rebooted twice, scanned for viruses and I haven't fiddled with any of the Windows settings recently.
I'd really appreciate if you could help me with this oddity.

Comment: If nothing has changed, try DISM, SFC... (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Followed the steps. Some files were damages and have been repaired (I guess that's good :). Unfortunately, the problem is still there.

Comment: How to perform a clean boot in Windows https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Followed the steps. Some files were damages and have been repaired

In this case run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  Start with the option to Keep Everything: This is best if it works because your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

This also keeps your current profile. If Keep Everything does not work, it is likely your main Windows User profile is damaged and you would need to back it up and replace the profile.

Comment: Cheers, it helped. I can finally switch again ^^.

Comment: Good news. Repair Install is a handy tool.